# TensorFlow feed an integer

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, convolution, conv-neural-network

I am trying to do a convolution over variable input sizes. To achieve that, I am using a batch size of 1. However, one of the nodes is a max pooling node which needs the shape of the input as a list `ksize`:

```
 pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=[1, self.input_size - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='VALID',
                name="pool")
```

Now, clearly the input_size can be inferred from the input (which is a placeholder):

```
self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="input_x")
```

But I can't use `self.input_x.get_shape()[0]` because the shape is dynamic. So I intend to pass the input size as feed_dict at each step. However, I can't figure out how to pass an integer in feed_dict. Every placeholder is a tensor, so if I do:

```
self.input_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(), name="input_size")
```

I would have to do `self.input_size.eval()` to get the int value, which gives me an error that I need to feed `input_size`. I guess it happens because eval triggers the computation BEFORE the training step happens, at which point there is no value for input_size.

Is there a way I can dynamically get an op that calculates the shape of the input or a way to pass an integer to a training step?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's the best way, but you can get dynamically the shape of `self.input_x` in a list with :

```
input_shape = tf.unpack(tf.shape(self.input_x))
```

`tf.shape(self.input_x)` give you a Tensor representing the shape of self.input_x and `f.unpack` convert it to a list of Tensor.

Now you can create your max pooling node with :

```
pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=tf.pack([1, input_size[1] - filter_size + 1, 1, 1]),
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='VALID',
                name="pool")
```

(if you needed the 2nd dimension of input_x)

Comment: It still returns a list of tensors. I need the actual value (integer) of the second dimension, and at runtime. That is why I am thinking of "feeding" this as a parameter, however, it looks like I can only feed Tensors?

Comment: Can you feed an integer with " input_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32) " ? It works for me but I'm on TF r0.8 and I didn't try with latest version.  For the problem of list of tensors, I modified my answer. I don't understand why, but tf.pack the ksize array should work...

Comment: This is an issue in TF. No matter what you do - ksize will be evaluated at construction time so this is not achievable.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. I usually get the shape of tensor dynamically for tf.reshape or tf.image.resize_images functions. I was hoping it works for tf.nn.max_pool...

Comment: Just a note: `tf.pack` was renamed to `tf.stack` in Tensorflow 1.0